# I reference my CSS page to my HTML and it simply won't have any effect

Tags: java, html, css

I am currently working on a java project and have made an html page with a design (css) page to accompany it. I have referenced it but it still won't have any effect. I hard reloaded the page still no changes. Don't really understand why this is happening. I keep getting "net::ERR_ABORTED 404" on localhost. The stylesheet file name is indeed correct (being loginStyle.css). They are also both located in the same folder. Would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```css
.btn-color {
  background-color: #0e1c36;
  color: #fff;
}

.profile-image-pic {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.cardbody-color {
  background-color: #ebf2fa;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:thymeleaf.org>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="loginStyle.css" />
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <h2 class="text-center text-dark mt-5">Welcome</h2>
      <div class="card my-5">

        <form class="card-body cardbody-color p-lg-5" th:action="@{/userLogin}" th:object="${user}" method="post">

          <div class="text-center">
            <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/03/31/19/56/avatar-1295397__340.png" class="img-fluid profile-image-pic img-thumbnail rounded-circle my-3" width="200px" alt="profile">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="User Name" th:field="*{Id}">
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password" th:field="*{password}">
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-color px-5 mb-5 w-100">Login</button></div>
          <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-center mb-5 text-dark">Not Registered?
            <a href="#" class="text-dark fw-bold"> Create an Account
                    </a>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: Right click, inspect, look in the network tab

Comment: It gave a preview of "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with given identifier."

Comment: So server issue, not HTML or CSS